# binary encoding of nonce 0

Tags: raw-transaction, rlp

Although probably not an issue in practice, I'm confused how nonce of zero is encoded in transactions.

According to RLP [doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP), `\x00` should be encoded as `\x00`. But the source code of [pyethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/transactions.py#L30) shows that `0` is encoded as empty string `''`, i.e. nothing.

> nonce is the number of transactions already sent by that account, encoded
>       in binary form (eg.  0 -> '', 7 -> '\x07', 1000 -> '\x03\xd8').

Apparently, the latter is used in practice. Why is it inconsistent with the RLP doc?

Answer (score 1):

In practice, leading zeroes may cause some problems across OS, for example, regarding big endian VS. little endian. In an other link (which I don't remember where it lies), it's said to an implementation just ignore such leading zeroes.

From the Ethereum yellow paper:

> When interpreting RLP data, if an expected fragment is decoded as a
>   scalar and leading zeroes are found in the byte sequence,  clients
>   are required to consider it non-canonical and treat it in the same
>   manner as otherwise invalid RLP data, dismissing it completely.